# How to use nodejs with ROS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rosnodejs

I have a project where I have users on the backend and I have go-karts run by rosbag which in turn is on the frontend.  I want to put my topics in a database but I have no idea what it could be, that's when I found the rosnodejs option.  Can anyone help me with how ROS works with nodejs?  I can't find one on the internet that is connected to port 9090, which works by default.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to learn about? I don't understand what you mean about port 9090. Have you already looked at the example in https://github.com/RethinkRobotics-opensource/rosnodejs/tree/kinetic-devel/src/examples ? (I'm a contributor to rosnodejs.)

Comment: Hello! thanks for your reply! I have worked with roslib.js so far with the following code:
var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({

    url:'ws://10.0.2.15:9090'

});
it used to connect to the ROS and when i started the bag and the roslaunch rosbridge server was connected then, but this roslaunch is not running in the example or it is not connected to the port.

Comment: rosnodejs is a native node.js client for ROS; roslib.js is a client-side library and uses rosbridge on the server (the robot). These two things are very different from one another.